# get id of an li with the text value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I have a code

`<li id="a1">Apple</li>`

What I need to do is with the text value "Apple" as input, I need to find the id of that li.

Is this possible in javascript / jquery?

Thanks in Advance ! ! !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) with `search string` like

```
alert($("li:contains('Apple')").attr("id"));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljzyhkqh/)

Comment: Yes This is it ! Thanks sadikhasan !

Comment: If in case we have an attribute 'attrib' from that we need to find id ! <li attrib="Apple" id="a1"> how to do this ?

Comment: Please can you ask as new question? So I can explain very well with new requirements

Answer (score 2):

using jquery get all li's and loop through them to find the text you're after. then if you find a match grab the id.

```
$(function(){

   var lis = $('li');

   $(lis).each(function(){
       if ($(this).text() === 'Apple')
          alert($(this).attr('id'));
   });

});
```

here's a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/3L5wnp2q/

Comment: Thanks Dewd ! thats Great Idea ! But I need it without looping the li's with the single line of query!